# Size of .apk file is more when packaged from command line in flex mobile app

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air, flex4.5

I have a built a mobile application using flash builder burrito and when i export the app from the builder the size of the apk file is say 1180KB,but when i try packaging the same application from the command line the size increases dramatically(to 2679KB).In both the cases if we see the size of swf file it is 2679KB only.So the builder is using some compression techniques to reduce the file size.Is there any options available in command line to do the same compression technique??.I have used the following command to package the swf file..

```
adt -package -target apk -storetype pkcs12 -keystore testCert.p12 projectRunTime.apk projectRunTime-app.xml projectRunTime.swf
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If I had to guess; I'd say that your command line is creating the APK from a debug build, not from a release build.  You said the SWF File size is the same, but I'm unsure what two SWFs you are comparing.

Comment: i am telling the swf that i compiled from command line and the swf from the builder

Answer (score 3):

Flash Builder uses ADT to package the APK. There are no extra compression options. To find out what is going on, I suggest that you unzip both the apk files and compare the file contents.